# restrict access to certain states depending on user roles in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am building an application and I would like to restrict access to the states depending on user roles. If a user tries to acess a restricted state I would like for him to be redirected to a default state based on his user role. How would I implement this?

I am guessing i need to use the $stateChangeStart event, but I'm not sure how I would implement it.

Note: for the purposes of the example, you can assume I have a factory which stores the user object and has his role.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.preventDefault()` inside your `$on()` handler, just as you would for any other event, to prevent the transition.